# Replacing all <br> with <br />

Tags: jquery, replace, line-breaks

I'm using this (jQuery) to replace all `<br>`s with `<br />` to clear out validation errors:

```
$("<br>").replaceAll("<br />");
```

but it doesn't reduce any validation errors. Does validator check the original source?

Comment: Yes, of course. I think you're missing the point of validation.

Comment: This is by far the worst way to go about fixing this.

Use an HTML doctype instead of an XHTML doctype if you want to use <br>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to do this. XHTML is dead. Switch your doctype to html 5 and go back to happily using unclosed tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: XHTML is not dead. XHTML 2 is no longer in active development, but there are still valid reasons to use XHTML, and it's not going anywhere. The problem with XHTML 1.1 is that most people don't serve their pages as xml, which is the main reason to use XHTML. But there are applications for this, so just because you choose not to use it, doesn't make it dead, and it doesn't make this a helpful answer.

Comment: Agree with the above comment, but in this case, it was helpful. I can change the doctype. :)

Comment: Well then your question should have been "How can I validate a page that has `<br>` in it?"

Answer (score 10):

JQuery will only fire after the document has been rendered. The process of the page loading will happen like the following

1. Request For page is made
2. Page is sent to client machine
3. Page Loads Up
4. Page is validated
5. JQuery Fires
6. break tags are replaced

I would recommend just doing a site-wide find and replace on all `<br>` tags and replace them with `<br />`

Comment: I agree, anything you can do outside of Javascript, you should.

Answer (score 5):

Validators do not run javascript. They parse the HTML and compare it to the schema for the declared doctype.

You will need to replace the `<br>` in your source files / views and not on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is parsed into the DOM model (step 3 in Gary's post), where `<br>` and `<br />` are considered equal. Adding an element to an HTML page through JavaScript, whether you use jQuery or any other means, will parse your element and add it to the DOM. How the internal HTML looked like is not important anymore for what the browser's concerned.

You can see this for yourself if you use `innerHTML`. Place the following in any HTML document (doesn't matter if it's XHTML, HTML4 or HTML 3.2):

```
<p onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">BR: <br />self close</p>
<p onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">BR: <br>open</p>
<p onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">BR: <BR>open capitals</p>
```

Load it in a browser and click on it.

On IE all three variants show up as `"<BR>"`, on FF, Chrome, Opera all three variants show up as `"<br>"`. This is how the browsers represent the HTML internally. Using valid HTML or invalid HTML with JavaScript will not change this. Worse: the internal HTML representation is not valid XHTML, even when the document is!

Answer (score 0):

first, as has been said the validators check the html file, and does not run anything.
beside, if you want to the html to be valid, there much more than 
 of course.. why don't you just use an html editor?